# List of all commits to bitbucket repo using python script

Tags: python, bitbucket, bitbucket-api, atlassian-python-api

I am trying to figure out how to get a list of all commits made to a bitbucket cloud repository over a given timeframe using the Atlassian Python API (https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/index.html)

According to this, there is a get_commits() function, but that only seems to work for a bitbucket server repository, not a bitbucket cloud. The Cloud functions seem significantly more limited in what data I can get from the repository.

My current code is able to pull some information on the repository:

```
from atlassian.bitbucket import Cloud

cloud = Cloud(username='<my username>',
              password='<my auth_password>',
              cloud=True)

repo = cloud.workspaces.get('<workspace>').projects.get('<project_id>').repositories.get('<repo_slug>')
print(repo)
```

Any idea on how I could print a list of all commits to this repo?

Comment: the API for listing the commits is `GET /repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/commits/. ` you should verify first by requests module for the URL like `url = "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/commits" `